# JavaScript split() function not working

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of string

```
"res1"
```

I want the output to be:

```
1
```

What I have tried till now:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = "res1";
    var result = str.split("res");
    document.write(result);//returns ,1
    var mystring = result.split(',').join("");

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = mystring;
}
```

The error which I receive is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: result.split is not a function
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You are trying to split the array..hence the error

Comment: Could you tell me (which part of the code have i to change???)

Comment: If all you're trying to do is get a number out of a string, you'd be better off with a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you generally want to get the last character of the string you could use something like:

```
var str = "res1";
str.substr(str.length - 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort

Comment: @SangameshDavey nice. then don't forget to set the answer to be the right one so others with the same problem can use it too. ^^

Comment: I am allowed to accept your answer right  only after 4 mins..Will do it..Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this:

```js
 function myFunction() {
       var str = "res1";
       var result = str.split("res"); // output => ["","1"]
       //document.write(result);//returns ,1
       //var mystring = result.split(',').join("");

       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result[1];
     }
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason yours isn't working is because when you call `.split()` it returns an array, so when you call `result.split(',')` you're calling that on an array, which array's do not have this method, which is why you are getting your error. The other answers show an alternative, but I wanted to highlight why you are getting that error.

Comment: @BM0e872,,Thanks Understood my mistake and thanks for telling me